# Is there a way to use javascript code without using <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm working on my online portfolio using prosite.com and I created some simple hover thingy using javascript (http://wojtek.szukszto.com/index.html). The problem is prosite.com won't allow me to use < script > tag... Is there any way to do it? Maybe as an external html? I don't know... I'm not really good in coding, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many ways. Search for "XSS injection" - that's just what you're trying to do. If you find one, that's a security issue for prosite.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have them as [DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events) like

```
<div onclick="alert('cat');">
  I <strong>Really</strong> want a cat!
</div>
```

```
 <body onload="//you can put a whole bunch of stuff here"></body>
 (It is equivalent to window.onload = function(){ //stuff })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your javascript code into external file and call in the head section of your html document

```
<head>    
<script src ="/JS/yourjsfile.js"></script>
</head>
```

hope that your host allows you to call JS in the head section

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is by stating the type of script. The ProSite already has javascript integrated within itself. I use:

```
<script type="javascript"> Code-Goes-Here </script>
```